# Weird unexpected '$dbname' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm experiencing a very weird parse error, all it says that it has unexpected T_VARIABLE on **line 21**.
Piece of code:

```
 mysql_connect("$host","$username","$passowrd") or die ("Data server is inaccesible);
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die ("User database is inaccesible");
$userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE activated='$activated'") or die ("Couldn't get account activation status");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $activated = $row['activated'];
  }

if ($activated == 0) { // We will read from database, and tell the user if their account has been activated by admin or not.
     $active = "No";

} else {

     $active = "Yes";
}
```

Everything looks fine actually, and it **SHOULD** work, but it doesn't, I found some similar questions, but none of their solutions worked (I wouldn't have asked, if any of them would've worked).
And yes I did include file which contains $dbname, $host etc...
Even if I put random letters/symbols anywhere else in the code, it still only shows this error, nothing else.
Don't judge me for not using mysqli (I know that mysql_... is deprecated).

Thanks for help.

Comment: obligatory DONT use mysql_* for new code

Comment: This question appears to be too localized because the problem a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Missing "

```
or die ("Data server is inaccesible);
```

Correctly:

```
or die ("Data server is inaccesible");
```

### HINTHINTHINT:

Use an IDE. Or at least Notepad++.

**Syntax highlight saves lives!**

(If you look at your code, you can see, that the `mysql_select_db` is maroonish - like the strings in the boxes...)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that, since my system contains more than 40 files, and this file has more than 200 lines of code.